# is there a way to sync repositories using nexus?

Tags: maven, synchronization, repository, nexus2

I am maintaining an internal maven repo with nexus (2.0.2). Due to organizational restrictions it sits on a machine with no internet connection (INT). Whenever new dependencies are needed, they is installed in a repository on a machine connected to the internet (EXT). Then the EXT repo is put on a pen drive and (after various security scans) is plugged into INT. EXT and INT are not connected in any other way.

What I would like to do is to add the pendrive repo to nexus and make nexus sync it with the internal repo.

I know it could be done with rsync, but I would prefer an integrated solution if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is no really way to do that better than you've already figured out. IMHO `rsync -a --delete` is the best solution that is able to work for you, with all these serious limitations you're talking about.